# How to generate 65 * 65 Qr code using zxing library file?

Tags: java, zxing, qr-code

I could generate 90 * 90 Qr Code using zxing library file ( version 1.7.0 ). But when I give less than 90 size to the image, Qrcode data filling area becomes too smaller , look at following example
[image]

While keeping size as 90 * 90,

[image]

While keeping size as 89*89..

I want to generate 65 * 65 Qr code, please help me.

```
String myCodeText = "Success";
String filePath = "D:/CrunchifyQR.png";
int size = 90;  
String fileType = "png"

Hashtable<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel> hintMap = new Hashtable<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel>();
hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);

QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
ByteMatrix byteMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(myCodeText,BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, size, size, hintMap);
int CrunchifyWidth = byteMatrix.getWidth() ;
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(CrunchifyWidth, CrunchifyWidth, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
image.createGraphics();

Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
graphics.fillRect(0, 0, CrunchifyWidth, CrunchifyWidth);
graphics.setColor(Color.GRAY);

byte[][] byteArr = byteMatrix.getArray();

for (int i = 0; i < CrunchifyWidth; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < CrunchifyWidth; j++) {
        int grayValue = byteArr[i][j] & 0xff; 
        if (grayValue != 0) {
            graphics.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
        }
    }
}

ImageIO.write(image, fileType, myFile);
```

Comment: Could you post some the code you use to do this so we can help you please?

Comment: Hi Wai Ha Lee , I have added my code above

Comment: Maybe it's because of the pixel ratio. There is no such thing as 1/2 a pixel.

Comment: The [QCodeWriter](http://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/qrcode/QRCodeWriter.html) class may be compensating for quiet zone padding. You should have, at a minimum, [four (4) modules of margin](http://www.qrcode.com/en/img/code/marginImage.png) between the edge of your image and the QR code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set MARGIN property to 1 (it's equal to 4 by default), like this:

```
Hashtable<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel> hintMap = new Hashtable<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel>();
hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);

hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 1);
```

I hope it helps!